# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 \cos(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$ by method of residues.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Im trying to solve $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 \cos(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$$ using the method of residues. This function has two simple poles at $x=\pm i$ and so $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 \cos(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}dx=2\pi i\text{Res}_{z=i }\frac{z^2 \cos(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}=2\pi i \lim_{z\to i} \frac d{dz}\Big[ (x-i)\frac{z^2 \cos(z)}{(z^2+1)^2}\Big]=2\pi i\lim_{z\to i}\frac d{dz}\Big[\frac{z^2\cos(z)}{(z+i)^2} \Big]=2\pi i \lim_{z\to i} \Big[ \frac{(z+i)^2(2z\cos z-z^2 \sin z)-2z^2(z+i)\cos z}{(z+i)^4} \Big]=2\pi i(-\frac{ei}{4})=\frac{\pi e}{4}$$
However wolfram alpha says that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 \cos(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}dx=0$$
I'm almost certain that the residue calculated above is correct, so why am I not able to apply the method here?

Comment: Since it is even function, the integration is not zero.

Comment: @duanduan But the integral is zero

Comment: On which closed curve are you integrating?

Comment: your application of the residue theorem is wrong

Comment: 'I'm almost certain that the residue calculated above is correct' ---No, your calculation is wrong. \begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2\cos x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^2+1}dx-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx\\&=\frac{\pi}{e}-\frac{\pi}{e}=0.\end{align}

Comment: Please, note that the function $f(z) = \dfrac{z^2 \cos z}{(z^2+1)^2}$ has two poles of order _two_ at $z=\pm i$, since it is: $(z^2+1)^2 = [(z-i)(z+i)]^2$. Anyway, if you're determined to use the Residue Theorem to evaluate the above integral, if $\gamma$ is a path such that the points $z = i$ and $z = -i$ lie inside it, then you have:
$$\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i \left[\mathrm{Res}_f(+i) + \mathrm{Res}_f(-i)\right],$$
and since $f$ is a even function, the two residues are opposite, as can be easily proven. Now, can you find a path that connects you to the answer to your question?

Comment: The integration path need not enclose borh poles.  Simply use a closed contour comprised of the real line segment from $(1)$ $-R$ to $R$ snd a semi_circular arc, centered at the origin, with radius $R$.  Also, don't use $\cos(z)$ as the integrand since it is unbounded as $|z|\to \infty$ (it has exponential growth on the arc) and we want the contribution from the integration on the arc to vanish as $R\to infty$.  I've posted a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C$ be a closed contour comprised of $(i)$ the real-line segment from $-R$ to $R$ and $(ii)$ the semi-circular arc of radius $R$, centered at the origin, and in the upper-half plane.  Then, we have for $R>1$

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(z^2+1)^2}\,dz&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(z^2+1)^2},z=i\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \lim_{z\to i}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(z+i)^2}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \lim_{z\to i}\left(\frac{2ze^{iz}+iz^2e^{iz}}{(z+i)^2}-\frac{2z^2e^{iz}}{(z+i)^3}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(-ie^{-1}/4 +ie^{-1}/4\right)\\\\
&=0 \tag 1
\end{align}$$

We also have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(z^2+1)^2}\,dz&=\int_{-R}^R\frac{x^2e^{ix}}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx+\int_0^\pi \frac{R^2e^{i2\phi}e^{iRe^{i\phi}}}{(R^2e^{i2\phi}+1)^2}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi \tag 2
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$, the second integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ approaches zero.  Therefore, putting everything together we find that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2e^{ix}}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx=0$$

and therefore since $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2\cos(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx=0$$